# Open Source counterpart to Euclidean Allocation

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I'm looking for a function that can perform something similiar to the Euclidean Allocation process in arcGIS (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Euclidean_Allocation/009z0000001m000000/) but using open source tools-- ideally Qgis or Gdal.

Alternatively, if there is a function that can take a polygon layer (e.g. map of the world) and run an algorithm similiar to Thiessen polygons-- that is, fill in the gaps in the extent using the nearest polygon that would be most helpful. For this latter solution, I'd prefer if I didn't have to convert boundaries to points.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your data: what the inputs are? There's more than one way to skin a cat! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Euclidean Allocation**

The only tool I know of, that specifically supports Euclidean Allocation based on euclidean distance calculation is [Whitebox](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/index.html) (see also their [Help section](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/Help/EuclideanAllocation.html)).

**Region Growing**

I don't know the exact problem you are working on, but my guess is you can also solve it with region growing - a process quite common in image segmentation and mostly based on euclidean distance allocation. Here are two tools supporting region growing algorithms.

[QGIS: Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/) - as well as the [source code](https://github.com/semiautomaticgit/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin) if you want the Python code

[ORFEO Toolbox](http://orfeo-toolbox.org/otb/) - as well as their [QGIS integration](http://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/Quantum_GIS_plugins)