# Interpolating parts of raster layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

I have the following raster layer [image]

The part in black have a value of 255, while the yellow parts have other values that goes from 0 to 255 depending on the color. The black part are the one that i want to interpolate since they have a value of 255 because no value were present, so it is like  they are null values.

Is there a way to interpolate/assign a value to the black parts and obtain a raster layer without them?

Comment: What is "/assing"?

Comment: Sorry i mean assign

Comment: Are you sure that the value isn't supposed to be 255 and is being not drawn because the nodata value is set to 255? How does it look if you set the nodata to 256 (out of range)? It's kind of hard to tell with your sample area if it could be expected to be very bright. One way to fill with adjacent values is to convert your raster to points then interpolate the points, it is tedious doing it that way though. If you're not too fussy about the value that gets filled have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120840/open-source-counterpart-to-euclidean-allocation and see if that helps

Comment: The area considered is much bigger, in this screenshot i took just a part,so i think that an interpolation can work because in general the area with no value are not so many. Anyway yes the area with value 255 represent no measurement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your value 255 is not set as nodata (*"it is like they are null values"*), I would suggest two steps - (1) Assign 255 as your Nodata cell. (2) Fill Nodata cells.

---

(1) Set Nodata cell by `gdal_translate`

1. From QGIS Processing Toolbox, activate `GDAL/OGR | [GDAL] Conversion | Translate (convert format)`.
2. There is an entry: `Nodata value, leave blank to take the nodata value from input`. Give it `255`.
3. Expand `Advanced parameters` (small black triangle), where you will see `Output raster type`. Select `Byte`.
4. Click on <kbd>Run</kbd>. You will get a new layer `Converted`.

(2) Fill holes by `Fill Nodata cells`

1. From QGIS menu, open `Raster | Analysis | Fill nodata`. Select `Converted` as the `Input layer`.
2. Set `Output file` name to be the output and click on <kbd>Run</kbd>.

---

Footnote about the choice of tool for (1) handling nodata value:

- GRASS has `r.null` tool which specifically handles nodata value. Today I had difficulty using this tool as it changed grid size for some unknown reason. (But it may worth a try).
- SAGA also handles nodata through its `Reclassify values` tool, but the output becomes Float32 grid (SAGA default setting).
- So I assumed gdal_translate is the tool to change nodata value for Byte-type dataset.

Comment: Thank you, this was very useful, the missing values were filled.

Comment: I had been looking for exactly this answer!