# Interpolating raster into continuous surface image using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

I have a raster of non-continuous surface with valid values and nodata values, and I'm trying to interpolate it into a continuous surface image without nodata values using QGIS.

Can anyone help?

The non-continuous surface (white area has nodata value and coloured area has valid values:

[image]

What I want to achieve using QGIS:

[image]

Comment: In ArcGIS I would use Euclidean Allocation but that has no counterpart in QGIS https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120840/open-source-counterpart-to-euclidean-allocation you could try converting your raster to points then use intepolation https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_interpolation.html to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Raster pixels to points**](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#raster-pixels-to-points) to convert the raster to point vector. Then you can [interpolate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html) using IDW interpolation or any other method (the SAGA toolbox has several algorithms).